# How to get intellisense for Styles outside of React Native component

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code

I'm writing React Native in VS Code. From inside a component, when I type something like

```js
<View style={{mar}}/>
```

the Intellisense pops up with all the `margin`-based suggestions for React Native styling (along with any other `mar`-based suggestions from my code or elsewhere).

However, this styling autocomplete only works from within a component. When defining my styles separately, as is convention in React Native, like this:

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  flatlistContainer: {
    mar
  },
}
```

I don't get the same suggestions when I type `mar` (this is just using `mar` as an example, throughout, of course).

Is there a way to fix this? It seems pretty silly since this is the place you usually define styles in RN and it's not working!

Comment: You can try react native snapshot or any other plugin for styling autocomplete in VCS